# A simple question on pipelined MIPS

Tags: digital-logic, computer-architecture

For branches/jumps the PC is always muxed from the MEM stage.  Why don't we mux it from the EX stage itself instead?

[image]

Comment: How would you implement relative branches?

Comment: @greybeard, any branches can be resolved in EX stage only. As you are not reading or writing to data memory in MEM stage. What problem do you see for relative brancahes

Comment: In the MEM stage, you have conditions available for conditional branches, mentioned in the schematic: *zero*.

Comment: All conditional branches can be resolved in EX stage. Because ALU would have compare unit to set/clear flags. Here"Zero" is also such flag. And it can be used in EX stage only. All conditional branches are regiseters/immediate value dependent. Can you give an example where keeping the MUX from EX stage would be a a hazard please.

Comment: Because if we propagate it to the next stage through pipeline registers like ZERO and PC, then we have to wait for one more clock cycle to fetch "New Jump Instruction"

Comment: @Revanth The ALU output is combinatorial. The only thing that is guaranteed is that the clock period will be set long enough such that when the ALU output is latched into EX/MEM, it is stable by then. If you pipe it from the combinatorial output rather than the latched value, how are you sure it's stable? And if you wait until the clock edge which guarantees it's stable then what have you really gained? I guess I'd like to see a lot more detailed thinking from you, rather than try and guess and/or suss it out bit by bit. Write more?

Comment: @periblepsis the stability issue will remain mostly same to latch it to the EX/MEM right. In the current scheme instead of wiring the shifted output to mux, we are wiring it to the EX/MEM latch/register. The mux/the pc update will be sequential. We will wait for the next clock edge just like the latch update.

Answer (score 0):

(There has been the Stanford MIPS Project, and MIPS I-V & MIPS32/64 as marketed by MIPS Technologies. There is MIPS as used in "higher education".)

It seems desirable to have conditional jumps and unconditional jumps handled uniformly. Conditional jumps depend on conditions established in the ALU/Execution stage - some of them late, like *carry*:
Doing anything with it but capture it in a pipeline register is bound to increase cycle time.